# MapView smooth annotation's location update

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I have 2 annotations on my mapView: current user location and a car location.

I'm getting the car location every 5 seconds from the server and moving the location of the car annotation.

The question is: How can I move it smoothly and not every 5 seconds?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can track the speed and direction of the car, you should be able to estimate its approximate position on the map between the 5s location updates. Obviously, this will be heuristic/approximate/ballpark location. You can experiment with tweaking the 5s figure to see if it yields better results.